# How can I create a C# solution that contains an application and class library project that have the same output assembly name?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a GUI project that is supported by a class library. Both belong to the same solution and serve a similar purpose so I would like to give them the same name. This should be possible since the file name for the GUI application would be `foo.exe` and `foo.dll` for the library. However, attempting this in practice causes the CLR to be unable to find one of the assemblies.

At first, part of the problem seems to be that the PDB file name is generated from the assembly name and not the file name, e.g. the PDB is named `foo.pdb` instead of `foo.exe.pdb`. Therefore one PDB overwrites the other. However, even in *Release* mode where a PDB is not needed, the assembly still fails to execute with the same exception, so perhaps the problem has nothing to do with debugging at all.

How can I create a solution that contains an application (exe) and class library (dll) with the same name?

Comment: Do you know that you can add dependencies to .exe assemblies just like you can with .dlls?

Comment: It'd be confusing from a .Net standpoint, because the assemblies would both be named Foo (that one is executable isn't a big deal). Why not name the projects `foo` and `FooLibrary` (so the files would be `foo.exe` and `FooLibrary.dll`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  The CLR locates assemblies by their *display* name.  The display name for both your EXE and your DLL project is "foo", it does not include a filename extension.  Accordingly, when the CLR needs to find the assembly "foo", it will first try "foo.EXE" and next "foo.DLL".  Clearly this will not work well in your case, your program will bomb when it tries to use a type from the class library.

You *must* use a different name.

Comment: I suppose this is a sad truth about the CLR. Thank you for confirming my suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

If having the same name is all you care about, then this is what I would suggest. I'm going to start from scratch here if you don't mind:

1. Create a blank solution.
2. Add two new solution folders, "App" and "Library".
3. Open Windows Explorer, go to your solution directory and create 2 directories with the same names, "App" and "Library"
4. Go back to Visual Studio, add your GUI project under "App". Let's call it "foo". Make sure you put it under your "App" directory you created in step 3.
5. Likewise, do the same thing for your library project, put it under "Library". Call it "foo" and make sure it goes into "Library" directory.
6. You should be able to compile it now.